# How to stream Realm Results to LiveData in Android Application

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-livedata

I am investigating the use of LiveData in my current Android Application.

The main screen of my application displays a list of data items that are retrieved from my local Realm database.

Currently I am retrieving all rows from Realm and then I post the entire list to my LiveData. This takes 5 seconds or more currently

```
final List<DataItemDO> dataItemDOs = DatabaseController.fetchShortlistedDataItems();

final List<DataItemUI> dataItemUIs = new ArrayList<>();

for (final DataItemDO dataItemDO : dataItemDOs) {
    final DataItemUI dataItem = constructDataItemUI(dataItemDO);
    dataItemUIs.add(dataItem);
}

DATA_ITEMS.postValue(dataItemUIs);
```

What I would like to do is to post each row to my LiveData so that my UX is more responsive or say post every 10 rows retrieved.

```
final List<DataItemDO> dataItemDOs = DatabaseController.fetchShortlistedDataItems();

final List<DataItemUI> dataItemUIs = new ArrayList<>();

for (final DataItemDO dataItemDO : dataItemDOs) {
    final DataItemUI dataItem = constructDataItemUI(dataItemDO);
    dataItemUIs.add(dataItem);

    DATA_ITEMS.postValue(dataItemUIs);
}
```

When I tried this approach I get the following exception:-

```
08-02 09:02:52.503 22134-22134/sutd.android E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: sutd.android, PID: 22134
    java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
        at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:860)
        at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:461)
        at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2827)
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:132)
```

I have a feeling that either LiveData transformations can resolve this issue or by employing LiveDataReactiveStreams.

I believe I need to construct an Emitter> and emit each row, I cannot see how to start.

How can I achieve the desired results to have my displayed list refresh each time I fetch a new row from Realm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could work for you (kotlin)(will return `LiveData<T!>`:

```
fun <T> Flowable<T>.toLiveData() = LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(this)
```

Comment: my publisher would be a List<DataItemUI>; how to create a publisher that is "backed" by constantly updated List<>?

Comment: can't your publisher be `toFlowable()`-ed ?